# Jquery functions conflict with other plugin jquery function

Tags: php, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I am using Same **jquery function** in two different WordPress plugins.
Both Plugins working fine individually, the problem is if I activate both then the script is working for one plugin other one not working(2nd plugin not working).

Can anybody give me a solution and tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't include jquery twice
2) make use of $ = jQuery.noConflict() if necessary

Answer (score 0):

you should use `jQuery.noConflict();` in the beaning of your jquery.
More Details :- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Similar question 
[How Can I remove Conflict in my Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149129/how-can-i-remove-conflict-in-my-jquery)
[How to be a jQuery no.conflict expert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721815/how-to-be-a-jquery-no-conflict-expert)