# Stop Conflict Between two jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, jquery-ui

I am working in one Web-base software, which is build in "codeigniter". In this software they used jQueryUI, bootstrap JQuery etc.

Here I want to implement inline editing functionality. I successfully implemented it but after Implementing inline editing functionality, other functionality of that not working properly because of conflict between two jQuery.

Here is my jquery code which we added :

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.auto').click(function(){

                $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                $(this).addClass('ajax');
                $(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="'+$(this).text().length+'" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');

                $('#editbox').focus();

          }
          );
</script>
```

I also put below code before above code for stopping jQuery conflict :

```
<script>
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean you are including two jQuery versions? BTW, any error in console? Could you provide any online link?

Comment: No actually I am not including 2 jquery version but i just put above code for inline edit and then functionaly of pop up not working. before posting that code new form opens like pop up but when i add this code it opens in that tab

Comment: Then i don't see why would you use jQuery noConflict() method (if not using any other lib which use `$`). To try to fix conflict between two jQuery plugins, first open your console to check for any error

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149129/how-can-i-remove-conflict-in-my-jquery  and check this for your reference https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: My Console showing "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " error only

Answer (score 1):

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ - `$.noConflict()` releases control of `$`, and assigns it the value previously assigned to it. Lower in the page you can see this:

> **Example: *Load two versions of jQuery (not recommended). Then,
>   restore jQuery's globally scoped variables to the first loaded
>   jQuery.***

```
<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script>
var $log = $( "#log" );

$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );

// Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded
// (the newer version)

jq162 = jQuery.noConflict( true );

$log.append( "<h3>After $.noConflict(true)</h3>" );
$log.append( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq162): " + jq162.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
```

Other than that, simply don't use `$` in the global scope. NEVER use `$` in the global scope. Use it only as a local parameter where it's needed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //you may now safely use $ inside here. Or if you pass a different parameter - use that
});
```

alternative:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jq) {
    //you may now safely use jq inside here. Or if you pass a different parameter - use that
    jq("#mydiv").addClass('ajax');
    //now that $ is not jQuery, but another library, you can also use that library
    $.nonJQueryFunctionOfSomeOtherLibraryUsing$Symbol();
});
```

Comment: I Apply both code but the result is same not working

Comment: Please go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and set up a working sample, so we can see what you write, and what's not working. I can't contribute more at this point, because I have no idea what you've tried.